# How can I convert a list of coordinates into an SF Multipolygon file?

Tags: r, r-sf

```
newdata
             V1        V2
1    -2.8701091 8273.6321
2     4.8298909 8273.6321
3    21.3298909 8279.1321
4    25.7298909 8281.3321
5    32.3298909 8285.7321
6    46.6298909 8298.9321
```

V1 is x and V2 is y and I want to know if there was a way to convert this into an sf multipolygon file. Newdata has 941 polygons and each polygon has roughly 19 rows each. Thank you! Here is a reproducible dataset for the first two polygons:

```
> dput(head(newdata, 38))
structure(list(.id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), V1 = c(-2.8701090548579, 
4.8298909451421, 21.3298909451421, 25.7298909451421, 32.3298909451421, 
46.6298909451421, 47.7298909451421, 55.4298909451421, 64.2298909451421, 
67.5298909451421, 67.5298909451421, 65.3298909451421, 54.3298909451421, 
52.1298909451421, 48.8298909451421, 46.6298909451421, 34.5298909451421, 
-2.8701090548579, -2.8701090548579, -1.79600509987251, 9.2039949001275, 
20.2039949001275, 25.7039949001275, 37.8039949001275, 41.1039949001275, 
44.4039949001275, 44.4039949001275, 38.9039949001275, 35.6039949001275, 
33.4039949001275, 32.3039949001275, 29.0039949001275, 20.2039949001275, 
16.9039949001275, 11.4039949001275, 0.403994900127497, -1.79600509987251, 
-1.79600509987251), V2 = c(8273.63213813615, 8273.63213813615, 
8279.13213813615, 8281.33213813615, 8285.73213813615, 8298.93213813615, 
8300.03213813615, 8313.23213813615, 8333.03213813615, 8356.13213813615, 
8381.43213813615, 8385.83213813615, 8401.23213813615, 8403.43213813615, 
8405.63213813615, 8406.73213813615, 8406.73213813615, 8395.73213813615, 
8273.63213813615, 7198.72511687208, 7198.72511687208, 7199.82511687208, 
7202.02511687208, 7213.02511687208, 7216.32511687208, 7222.92511687208, 
7236.12511687208, 7251.52511687208, 7258.12511687208, 7261.42511687208, 
7262.52511687208, 7264.72511687208, 7269.12511687208, 7270.22511687208, 
7271.32511687208, 7271.32511687208, 7270.22511687208, 7198.72511687208
)), row.names = c(NA, 38L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: How are you designating polygons? i.e. how do you know which rows are points in which polygon?

Comment: So this is after cutting off the column with the polygon number label so I can add it back easily.

Comment: Why did you cut that off though? To be able to help you, I think that's going to be necessary. Otherwise I don't have a way of knowing that (for example) rows 1, 2, and 3 should become one polygon and rows 4, 5, and 6 should become another. I think you'll also need a few more rows to make this a good example—with 6 points, it's only possible to make 2 triangles. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making a reproducible example that is easier for folks to help with.

Comment: Ah I apologize for the low quality question. If I can explain a bit more, I basically combined 941 different polygons with all of their coordinates into one giant dataframe. Each polygon has 19 rows worth of coordinates that connect back to the first coordinate. Thus, rows 1-19 = polygon 1, 20-38 = polygon 2, etc.

Comment: Are you sure each polygon comprises 19 rows? 941 %% 19 = 10. Perhaps you are missing a third column which groups the polygons?  Could you make the question reproducible by adding data which can be easily copied for two polygons into the question; use `dput(head(newdata, 38)`.

Comment: That was a mistake! I meant each of the 941 polygons had 19 rows each... sorry about the confusion. And yes, I do have a third column that indicates which polygon they belong to.  And yes, I will do that.

Comment: `sfheaders::sf_multipolygon(obj = newData, polygon_id = ".id")`

Comment: Absolutely beautiful thank you for the solution!

Comment: Oh for some reason it only saves it under 1 feature with 1 field... Is there a way that the multipolygon can tell they are 941 separate polygons?

Comment: whichever column of data specifies the MULTIPOLYGON id, use that as the `multipolygon_id = ` argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting R objects to {sf} objects is exactly the use-case for [{sfheaders}](https://github.com/dcooley/sfheaders)

If your `.id` column specifies each POLYGON within a single MULTIPOLYGON, then use the argument `polygon_id = ".id"`

```r
library(sf)
library(sfheaders)

sfheaders::sf_multipolygon(
  obj = newData
  , polygon_id = ".id"
  , x = "V1"
  , y = "V2"
)

Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 1 field
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -2.870109 ymin: 7198.725 xmax: 67.52989 ymax: 8406.732
CRS:           NA
id                       geometry
1  1 MULTIPOLYGON (((-2.870109 8...
```

If your `.id` column represents each MULTIPOLYGON, use the argument `multipolygon_id = ".id"`

```r
sfheaders::sf_multipolygon(
 obj = newData
 , multipolygon_id = ".id"
 , x = "V1"
 , y = "V2"
)

Simple feature collection with 2 features and 1 field
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -2.870109 ymin: 7198.725 xmax: 67.52989 ymax: 8406.732
CRS:           NA
.id                       geometry
1   1 MULTIPOLYGON (((-2.870109 8...
2   2 MULTIPOLYGON (((-1.796005 7...
```